# CASE Multiple values on Athena Presto

Tags: sql, presto

I'm looking for some advice.

I have multiple values that I wish to code to the same output, but Athena doesn't seem to recognise the SQL.

```sql
CASE customer_name
WHEN 'Aa' or 'Ar' or 'Aar' or 'Aaro' THEN 'Aaron' END as customer_name
```

I want to avoid doing the below:

```sql
CASE customer_name
WHEN 'Aa' THEN 'Aaron'
WHEN 'Ar' THEN 'Aaron'
WHEN 'Ar' THEN 'Aaron'
WHEN 'Ar' THEN 'Aaron'
END as customer_name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can move the field into the 'WHEN' clause:

```sql
WITH dataset ( customer_name) AS
(
  VALUES
      ('Aa'),
  ('Ar'),
  ('Ar'),
  ('Ar'),
  ('B')
)

 SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN customer_name IN ('Aa', 'Ar', 'Aar', 'Aaro') THEN 'Aaron'
    END AS customer_name
FROM dataset
```

Output:

| customer_name |
| --- |
| Aaron |
| Aaron |
| Aaron |
| Aaron |
|  |